# PySpark to_date function returns null for week 1 of the year

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, week-number

When I use week of year in the `to_date` function, the first week of the year returns a null for many years.

```py
df=pyrasa.sparkSession.createDataFrame([["2013-01"],["2013-02"],["2017-01"],["2018-01"]],["input"])
df.select(func.col("input"),func.to_date(func.col("input"),"yyyy-ww").alias("date")) \
  .show()
```

```
+-------+----------+
|  input|      date|
+-------+----------+
|2013-01|      null|
|2013-02|2013-01-06|
|2017-01|2017-01-01|
|2018-01|      null|
+-------+----------+
```

Why is this? Is it a bug in the `to_date` function?

Comment: Which Spark version do you use?

Comment: Also, for 2013-02 you got 2013-01-06 which is Sunday. Do you really want Sunday, or should it be Monday, i.e. 2013-01-07?

Comment: Hi ZygD. Thanks for the suggestions. The spark forum said that w should not be supported. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-39433 The udf looks like it would work, but I would prefer to avoid the overhead of udfs, so I'll avoid using weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Just for the record, pandas_udf should not be regarded in the same way as pyspark.sql.functions.udf. pandas_udf is vectorized, it doesn't run for every row like regular udfs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

df.withColumn('date', expr("date(input)")).show()

+-------+----------+
|  input|      date|
+-------+----------+
|2013-01|2013-01-01|
|2013-02|2013-02-01|
|2017-01|2017-01-01|
|2018-01|2018-01-01|
+-------+----------+
```

Comment: The value in row 2 does not match OP's result. I think he has another algorithm in his mind.

Comment: @ZygD Where has OP stated that?

Comment: In his script, he uses `ww` which is supposed to mean week, not month.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following `pandas_udf`. It works using the latest Spark version, but I can see from the result that you use earlier than Spark 3 version. I used this function, because in some cases there's no way to do it even in Spark 3. Spark move from version 2.4 to 3 changed quite much in datetime.

`format` tweaking may be required in your case if the function works at all. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) are the format codes.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
@F.pandas_udf('date')
def year_week_to_date(year_week: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.to_datetime(year_week + '-1', format='%G-%V-%u')

df = df.withColumn('date', year_week_to_date(F.col('input')))

df.show()
# +-------+----------+
# |  input|      date|
# +-------+----------+
# |2013-01|2012-12-31|
# |2013-02|2013-01-07|
# |2017-01|2017-01-02|
# |2018-01|2018-01-01|
# +-------+----------+
```